# Modificando un formulario con phpmailer

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

estoy haciendo una modificaciones a una web que ya esta hosteada,esta hecha con Laravel 5 y Bootstrap, el problema es que el formulario no funciona desde hace un par de días porque el hosting ya no soporta la función mail() de PHP,el soporte técnico del hosting me dijo que la solución sería usar una librería como PHPMailer para que puedan envíar los formularios, pero no se bien como implementarlo adjunto el código.
Hola, estoy haciendo una modificaciones a una web que ya esta hosteada,esta hecha con Laravel 5 y Bootstrap, el problema es que el formulario no funciona desde hace un par de días porque el hosting ya no soporta la función mail() de PHP,el soporte técnico del hosting me dijo que la solución sería usar una librería como PHPMailer para que puedan envíar los formularios, pero no se bien como implementarlo adjunto el código.

```js
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class ConsultaEmail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $nombre;
    public $email;
    public $celular;
    public $mensaje;
    
    public function __construct($nombre,$email,$celular,$mensaje)
    {
        // 
        $this->nombre=$nombre;
        $this->email=$email;
        $this->celular=$celular;
        $this->mensaje=$mensaje;

    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
       $mail= $this
         ->from('web@caf.com.ar','CAF Web')
         ->view('mail.consulta')
         ->subject('Nueva Consulta Web de '.$this->nombre);
        
         return $mail;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
@extends('layouts.base')

@section('contenido')
<style>
  .header-1 .header-top:before{display: none; padding-top: 0px;}

</style>
 <body id="category" class="lang-en country-gb currency-gbp layout-left-column page-category tax-display-enabled category-id-3 category-computer-networking category-id-parent-2 category-depth-level-2">
    
      
    
    <main id="main-site" class="displayhomenovtwo">
    
          


             @include('partials.header2')

<div id="header-sticky">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-between">
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center col-xl-3 col-md-3">
          <div class="contentstickynew_verticalmenu"></div>
          <div class="contentstickynew_logo"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="contentstickynew_search col-xl-7 col-md-6"></div>
        <div class="contentstickynew_group d-flex justify-content-end col-xl-2 col-md-3"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>          

      
        
<aside id="notifications">
  <div class="container">
    
    
    
      </div>
</aside>
      
          <div id="wrapper-site" class="mb-40">
                  
         <nav data-depth="1" class="breadcrumb-bg">
  <div class="container-fluid no-index pl-0 pr-0">
    <div class="breadcrumb mb-40" style="border-radius: 0px;">
        <div class="container pl-0">
    <ol itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">
              <li class="pl-38">
          <a itemprop="item">
            <span itemprop="name">CONSULTAS</span>
          </a>
        
        </li>
          </ol>
    </div> 
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>          
                        

              
  <div class="container no-index">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="content-wrapper" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
          

  <div id="main">
    
      
  
    
      <section id="content" class="page-content">        
        
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 pl-36 colregistro">
       <section class="register-form">
        <h4 class="verde2" style="font-size: 2.2rem;">FORMULARIO DE CONSULTA</h4>
        <p class="mb-40">Complete con sus datos el siguiente formulario y pronto nos pondremos en contacto. Muchas gracias.</p>
  
      

  <form action="" id="customer-form" class="js-customer-form" method="post">
    <section>
      
                  
            
  <input type="hidden" name="id_customer" value="">


          
                  
              <div class="form-group row no-gutters">
 

    <div class="col-md-4 form-control-comment right">
          </div>
  </div>


          
                  
              <div class="form-group row no-gutters">
    <label class="col-md-3 form-control-label mb-xs-5 required">
              Nombre y Apellido :
          </label>
    <div class="col-md-7">
      
        <input
          class="form-control"
          name="nombre"
          type="text"
          id="nombre"
          value=""
                              required        >
        
      
      
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 form-control-comment right">
          </div>
  </div>


          
                  
              <div class="form-group row no-gutters">
    <label class="col-md-3 form-control-label mb-xs-5 required">
              Email :
          </label>
    <div class="col-md-7">
      
        <input
          class="form-control"
          name="email"
          type="email"
          id="email"
          value=""
                              required        >
        
      
      
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 form-control-comment right">
          </div>
  </div>


          
                  
              <div class="form-group row no-gutters">
    <label class="col-md-3 form-control-label mb-xs-5 required">
             Celular :
          </label>
    <div class="col-md-7">
      
        <input
          class="form-control"
          name="celular"
          type="text"
          id="celular"
          value=""
>
    </div>
     <div class="col-md-4 form-control-comment right">
          </div>
  </div>


   <div class="form-group row no-gutters">
    <label class="col-md-3 form-control-label mb-xs-5 required">
              Mensaje :
          </label>
    <div class="col-md-7">
      
        <textarea
          class="form-control"
          name="email2"
          type="text"
          id="mensaje"
          value="" rows="6"
                                required      ></textarea>
        
      
      
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 form-control-comment right">
        
          </div>
  </div>


          
                  
                 
          
          



          
                
      
    </section>

    
      <footer class="form-footer clearfix">
        <div class="row no-gutters mt-10">
          <div class="col-md-9 offset-md-3">
            <p style="font-size: 12px; color: red;">* campo obligatorio</p>
            <input type="hidden" name="submitCreate" value="1">
            
                 <button class="btn btn-primary bg-azul3 hover-bg-verde2" style="border: none; font-weight: 600;" type="submit" id="envConsulta">
                Enviar
              </button>
            
          </div>
        </div>
      </footer>
    

  </form>


      </section>
     </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 hidden-sm-down">  
         <img src="{{asset('images/otros/consultas.jpg')}}" alt="" style="width: 100%">
      </div>
</div>

      </section>
    

    
      <footer class="page-footer">
        
          <!-- Footer content -->
        
      </footer>
    

  </div>


        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


            
      </div>

 <footer class="footer footer-four">
  <div class="inner-footer">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
            @include('partials.suscribirme')

<div class="nov_row-full-width clearfix w-100"></div>
  @include('partials.novedades')

  <div class="nov_row-full-width clearfix w-100"></div>

  
     
     @include('partials.guia')

<div class="nov_row-full-width clearfix w-100"></div>

      </div>
    </div>
   
@include('partials.footer')

</footer>
<div class="canvas-overlay"></div>
<div id="back-top">
  <span>
    <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-up"></i>  </span>
</div>              
    </main>
    
      <div id="mobile_top_menu_wrapper" class="hidden-md-up">
        <div class="content">
          <div id="_mobile_verticalmenu"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    

    <div id="mobile-pagemenu" class="mobile-boxpage d-flex hidden-md-up">
        <div class="content-boxpage col">
          <div class="box-header d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
              <div class="title-box">Menu</div>
              <div class="close-box">Cerrar</div>
          </div>
          <div class="box-content">
            <div id="_mobile_top_menu" class="js-top-menu"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="mobile-blockcart" class="mobile-boxpage d-flex hidden-md-up">
        <div class="content-boxpage col">
          <div class="box-header d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
              <div class="title-box">Carrito</div>
              <div class="close-box">Cerrar</div>
          </div>
          <div id="_mobile_cart" class="box-content"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
  



      <div id="blockcart-modal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" style="display: none;">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header"> 
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <i class="material-icons close">close</i>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 divide-right">
            <div id="product">
            <div class="row no-gutters main-productdetail" data-product_layout_thumb="bottom_thumb" style="position: relative;">
                <div class="col-xs-12 box-image">
                
                  <section class="page-content" id="content">
                    
                      
                        
  <div class="images-container bottom_thumb">
  
    <div class="product-cover">
      <img
        class="js-qv-product-cover img-fluid"
        src="http://demo.vinovathemes.com/prestashop_savemart/24-large_default/nullam-sed-sollicitudins-mauris.jpg"
        alt=""
        title=""
        style="width:100%;"
        itemprop="image"
      >
      <div class="layer hidden-sm-down" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#product-modal">
        <i class="fa fa-expand"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  

  
      <div class="js-qv-mask mask only-product">
        <div class="product-images slick-images" data-vertical="false" data-autoplay="false" data-autoplayTimeout="6000" data-items="4" data-margin="10" data-nav="true" data-dots="false" data-loop="false" data-items_mobile="3">
                      <div class="item thumb-container">
              <img
                class="img-fluid thumb js-thumb  selected "
                data-image-medium-src="http://demo.vinovathemes.com/prestashop_savemart/24-medium_default/nullam-sed-sollicitudins-mauris.jpg"
                data-image-large-src="http://demo.vinovathemes.com/prestashop_savemart/24-large_default/nullam-sed-sollicitudins-mauris.jpg"
                src="http://demo.vinovathemes.com/prestashop_savemart/24-medium_default/nullam-sed-sollicitudins-mauris.jpg"
                alt=""
                title=""
                itemprop="image"
              >
            </div>
            <div class="item thumb-container slick-slide slick-active" data-slick-index="2" aria-hidden="false" style="width: 120px;" tabindex="0">
              <img class="img-fluid thumb js-thumb " data-image-medium-src="http://demo.vinovathemes.com/prestashop_savemart/26-medium_default/nullam-sed-sollicitudins-mauris.jpg" data-image-large-src="http://demo.vinovathemes.com/prestashop_savemart/26-large_default/nullam-sed-sollicitudins-mauris.jpg" src="http://demo.vinovathemes.com/prestashop_savemart/26-medium_default/nullam-sed-sollicitudins-mauris.jpg" alt="" title="" itemprop="image">
            </div>
               
                  </div>
      </div>
  
  </div>

                      
                    
                  </section>
                
              </div>
  
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
           <div class="col-md-6 divide-right">
            <div class="row no-gutters">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="h4 product-name" style="font-size: 24px;" id="producto-nombre"></div>
                                <div id="producto-datos"></div>
                                <div id="producto-potencias" class="mt-15"></div>
                                <div id="producto-temperaturas" class="mt-15"></div>

                      <div class="product-price">£24s.00</div>  
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Continue shopping</button>
        <a href="//demo.vinovathemes.com/prestashop_savemart/en/cart?action=show" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>Proceed to checkout</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="modalconsulta" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content" style="border-radius: 25px;background-color: white;">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center" style="margin-bottom: 20px; margin-top: 20px;">
            <img src="{{asset('images/popregistro.png')}}"  style="width: 80px" alt="">
          <h3 class="verde2" style="font-size: 1.7rem">Tu consulta fue enviada con éxito</h3> 
          <h4 style="font-size: 1.4rem;">Pronto nos pondremos en comunicación</h4>   

          <img src="{{asset('images/logo-caf2.png')}}"  style="width: 50px; margin-top: 15px;" alt="">  
   

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>


     @stop

     @section('scripts')
      <script> $( ".deshabilitar" ).removeClass( "active" )</script>
     @stop
```

Comment: Cuál es el error?

Comment: al momento darle al botón de enviar el puntero se transforma en un icono de prohibido y en la consola dice: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
enviarConsulta:1" y no envía el correo.

Comment: Si quieres probar la pagina web es : http://caflex.com.ar/consultas

Comment: No se donde te da el 404 lo que yo veo es un 500 con lo siguiente: `"message": "syntax error, unexpected 'borrar' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)",
    "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError",
    "file": "/home/caflexsrl/caf/app/Mail/ConsultaEmail.php",
    "line": 34` es decir error en la linea 34 de `ConsultaEmail.php`

Comment: Ahí lo modifique me había comido unas palabras porque estaba probando algo haber si funcionaba, ahora me da el error 500 que te especifique.